# JQuery Obtaining value or text of active li tab using data-tab attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems getting the value / text of an `<li>` contained in `<ul>` of class "`tabs`"

Here's the HTML structure.

```
<div class="modal_body">
    <div id="sub_container_div">
        <ul class="tabs" id="tabs_ul">
            <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab1li">Tab 1</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab2li">Tab 2</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab3li">Tab 3</li>
        </ul>
        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!--TAB 1-->
        <div class="tab-content current" id="tab1div">TAB 1</div>
        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!--TAB 2-->
        <div class="tab-content current" id="tab2div">TAB 2</div>
        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!--TAB 3-->
        <div class="tab-content current" id="tab3div">TAB 3</div>

        <div class="modal_footer">
            <button  id="btn_save">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to display the tabs and switch to different tabs. However, I can't get the active tab. I tried several ways which I found in other questions here in `SO`

In my JS file,

```
$('#btn_save').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var active = $('#tabs_ul li').attr('data-tab');
    //var active = $("#tabs_ul .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");
    alert(active);
});
```

This line

```
var active = $('#tabs_ul li').attr('data-tab');
alert(active);
```

returns the data-tab value. However, when I switch to another tab and click the save button, it just returns the same data-tab value but not the active one.

For example, If I click "TAB 1", it will return "tab1li" then If I click on "TAB 2", it still returns "tab1li" instead of "tab2li"

When using `data-tab` attribute, what is the correct way to get the `data-tab` **value of the active** tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way `$('#tabs_ul li').attr('data-tab');` you are always getting the first `li` child of `tabs_ul` id, that's why you see always the first one.

You need to get the one with the `current` class too.

```
$('#tabs_ul li.current').attr('data-tab');
```

This implies that you have to manage the `current` class, if this is already not implemented with what you are using.

Then in `jQuery` you can get the data attributes directly through `data()` method:

```
$('#tabs_ul li.current').data('tab');
```

Comment: Minor note: I would suggest `$('[data-tab].current').data('tab')` instead. Better selector (not as HTML structure-dependent) and makes use of `$.data()` which is easier to read (and probably execute).

Comment: @Jeto agree with Jeto even if that's outside the scope of his issues. Editing